# Замена всех пикселей изображения черным цветом

Tags: gd, php

Привет, народ! Опять встал, не могу сдвинуться.
Задача: взять PNG изображение, в котором есть прозрачные, полупрозрачные, и не прозрачные пикселы, и заменить все непрозрачные пикселы черным цветом, а все полупрозрачные пикселы заменить тоже черным цветом, но сохраняя при этом полупрозрачность.
Вот начало кода:

```
 $im = imagecreatefrompng('img/1.png');
```

(да да, дальше уже надо начать обесцвечивать, и с этой строкой сижу уже оочень много верени)

Прошу помощи!

Есть идеи сделать это через два цикла, и пройтись по каждому пикселу, но что то не могу собрать все мысли в кучу, а так же знания о функциях библиотеки GD

Comment: мне кажется, для этого лучше подойдет imagemagic, по идее хватит просто яркость до нуля понизить картинки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все таки сам дошел. Вот ответ если кому пригодится:

```
$overlay = imagecreatefrompng('img/overlay/1.png');
    $color = array(255, 0, 0);
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize('img/overlay/1.png');
    for ($i = 1; $i < $height; $i++) {
        for ($u = 1; $u < $width; $u++) {
            $color_index = imagecolorat($overlay, $u, $i);
            $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($overlay, $color_index);
            if($rgb['alpha'] < 127 ){
                $color2 = imagecolorallocatealpha($overlay, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2], $rgb['alpha']);
                imagesetpixel($overlay, $u, $i, $color2);
            }
        }
    }
    imagepng($im, 'img/overlay/img.png');
```